# Replace drive letter with string label

Tags: windows, mapped-drive

On my Windows Server I have many mapped remote drives e.g. X:, Z:, M: and so on. Next to drive letters I see the path where it’s mapped.
That’s fine for me.
The issue is when list those drives in another server.
From another server I see only drive letters but not paths
Hence it’s difficult to recognize what it represents
I tried tied to replace letter with some string label but it failed
Do you have a clue how to replace letter for more descriptive label ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe someone could help you, if you mention what system "another server" ist running.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are mapping network shares to driveletters and are then network sharing those entire drives again ? Why dont you just make use of the more discriptively named network shares on the 'other server' ?

Comment: By another server I mean Windows 2019 Datacenter and app which I use is Azure Data Studio

Comment: Regarding second comment: I use one server Windows Datacenter 2019. I map network shares to 5 other servers and map has a label and the path. That’s OK for me. Then from inside of Azure Data Studio in Workspace I add those labels. The issue is that in Workspace they only display the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, select *This PC*. Now, open the View tab, and select layout: *Details*. Then, right click on a column header and make sure *Network location* is checked

Comment: thanks for heads-up. I followed your steps. It really change Details and add this column but didn't have anything in ADS Workspace ... I still see only one letter. BTW: I found a workaround: instead of Map Network Drive I used Add Network Location. Actually result is almost the same but the difference is that when I hover over the letter it displays the path. This is much more convenient. I would prefer Map instead on Network location because it's more permanent .. but this could be a work-around for me

Comment: @susik You mentioned ADS only in a comment. Please add all relevant information to the question itself, because comments may be deleted, and not everyone reads them. A screenshot of where exactly you want to see the locations would also help